# Is is possible to update a version of my app with price change at the same time

Tags: ios, sandbox, app-store-connect

I want to change the price of my app from free to paid. In my code, I use the user's first app version as the variable of if they have paid for the app since receipt validation gives me a purchase date so if they purchased it for free it is 'paid'. So I want to be able to send me an update and the price change at the same time.

I have thought of just letting it slide and if some people get my latest version for free, just let it be.

I also tried to maybe set the dates for update release and price change to be the same, but the timing will still be off because the time can be set. I don't know if setting a date for price change means it takes effect at midnight (12 AM ) if I say change the price for the date set to tomorrow. or will it be 9 PM.

Comment: There's no 100% guarantee, but you can do both a) scheduled release of the new version and a b) planned price change. You should be able to set the times for both over at App Store Connect. Still possible that due to caching etc. some might get it for free.

Comment: @Max do you mind putting that as an answer so I can check it as a approved answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 100% guarantee, but you can do both a) **scheduled release** of the new version and a b) **planned price change**. You should be able to set the times for both over at App Store Connect. Still possible that due to caching etc. some might get it for free